# How to solve Textview setText() is on a null object reference

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

So I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

I ran the debugging tool and these lines are null:

```
TextView leftMessageView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.leftmsgr);
leftMessageView.setText(Servermessage);
```

This is the function where its coming from:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    View row;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ChMessage chMessageObj = getItem(position);
    if (chMessageObj.left) {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.leftmessage, parent, false);
    }else{
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rightmessage, parent, false);
    }

        TextView rightMessageView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rightmsgr);
        TextView leftMessageView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.leftmsgr);
        rightMessageView.setText(chMessageObj.message);
        leftMessageView.setText(Servermessage);

    return row;
}
```

Not sure why its not null?

Any Help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: It looks like at least one of the views you're trying to reference in your layout cannot be found.  Double check to make sure that you have a TextView in your layout that corresponds to the view ids your referencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to fix the `NullPointerException` with this code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) 
{   
    View row;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ChMessage chMessageObj = getItem(position);
    if (chMessageObj.left) {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.leftmessage, parent, false);
    }else{
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rightmessage, parent, false);
    }

        TextView rightMessageView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rightmsgr);
        TextView leftMessageView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.leftmsgr);
        if (rightMessageView!=null) {
          rightMessageView.setText(chMessageObj.message);
        }
        if (leftMessageView!=null) {
          leftMessageView.setText(Servermessage);
        }

    return row;
}
```

Then, I don't if it is correct that the TextView is null. Check your XML layout. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much that worked perfectly! Really appreciate it!